# What is the "right" way to log while running in Sinatra's application scope?

Tags: ruby, logging, sinatra

I am playing around with writing a Sinatra app. I'd like to log something from the configuration blocks. However, that runs in the application scope, which doesn't include the logger methods if I do `enable :logging` in my configure block. Is there some normal way to log messages from the configure blocks while respecting whatever log configuration I have in effect?

Currently, I do something like the following:

```
class Blah < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    enable :logging
    @@log = Logger.new("/dev/stderr")
    @@log.info "blah"
  end
end
```

I'd rather use whatever logger is configured and default to one setup by the `enable :logger` line. Something similar to the following would be ideal:

```
class Blah < Sinatra::Base
  configure do
    enable :logging
    logger.info "blah"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As of 1.3 (i think) Sinatra ships with a logger like you described, but it writes by default to STDOUT and STDERR, if you want to hit it to a file add this to your config.ru:

```
logger = Logger.new('log/awesome_app.log')

use Rack::CommonLogger, logger
run AwesomeApp
```